# add libgdx.zip file in eclipse

Tags: android

How to add libgdx.zip file in eclipse for my android game application using libgdx framework.

Answer (score 3):

The ["MyFirstTriangle"](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/MyFirstTriangle) tutorial on the libgdx site does a good job of explaining the whole project setup.